# Content Type and Required fields in the form - How to ask in form for Required Values

Tags: content-type

Everything is going good, when I adding single document, by add document. I have got a form with required field  by content type. And I could choose optional Content Type. But when in Sharepoint 2013 I tried to add document, or much document by drag and drop adding it dont show me this form. Its adding me this document to the document with Chaced Out option. When I try to Check In this show me the Corelation Error that I forgot to put required fierld to document. I must take a Field Propeties, and then is Show Me the form with Required Field. Can I put this form with sameone miss any Required field ? Not ih all this steps.

Comment: You should really do a spellcheck on your post, you seem to have a pretty straight forward issue but it is hard to grasp it from your post

Comment: if I understood your problem correctly, I think I had the same problem and it was related to using Chrome or Firefox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is rather not a browser issue, it is standard SharePoint behaviour. If you add a single document via **Upload** button, SharePoint will present you with Properties modal instantly and you will be able to provide all required information and Check In document at the end.

When using Drag'n'Drop functionality, SharePoint does not show Properties window (which would be impossible for multiple documents at the same time), but instead it puts all the files in Checked Out state, which requires edition of Properties before Checking them in.

In this case it is impossible to upload multiple documents at the same time and fill required information for all them in one step. You have to edit properties for all of them when they are uploaded.